# Preservation of variance for log-normal variables under change of measure

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, mathematical-finance

Aim: to show that changing a probability measure via the application of a Radon-Nikodym derivative preserves variance of a log-normally distributed random variable (for the case when variance is non-stochastic, i.e. constant in $\omega$): **including discrete random variables that converge to log-normal in the limit.**

### 1. Continous Case:

I go with the well-known Geometric-Brownian-Motion model:

$$X_T:=X_0+\int_{h=0}^{h=T}\mu X_hdh+\int_{h=0}^{h=T}\sigma X_hdW_h$$

Above, $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are both constant, and the solution to the SDE is:

$$ln\left(\frac{X_T}{X_0}\right)=\mu T-0.5\sigma^2T+\sigma W_T$$

Which means:

\begin{equation}
\boxed{ln\left(\frac{X_T}{X_0}\right)\sim N\left(\mu T-0.5\sigma^2T,\sigma \sqrt{T}\right)} (1)
\end{equation}

If we want to eliminate or change the drift $\mu$ in the original SDE, we can work with the solution to the SDE above as follows:

$$ln\left(\frac{X_T}{X_0}\right)=\mu T-0.5\sigma^2T+\sigma W_T=\\=\mu T-0.5\sigma^2T+\sigma W_T+rT-rT=\\=-0.5\sigma^2T+\sigma\left(W_T+\frac{\mu-r}{\sigma}T\right)+rT$$

Defining $\hat{\mu}:=\frac{\mu-r}{\sigma}$, we can apply Girsanov Theorem to $W_T+\hat{\mu}T$ above as follows:

$$\frac{\mathbb{dQ}}{\mathbb{dP}}=exp\left(-W_T\hat{\mu}+0.5\hat{\mu}^2 T\right)$$

To get:

$$ln\left(\frac{X_T}{X_0}\right)=r T-0.5\sigma^2T+\sigma W_T^{\mathbb{Q}}$$

If we set $r=0$, the drift term would be eliminated.

**Conclusion**: We see that applying the Radon-Nikodym derivative has changed the drift, but preserved the variance of the variable $X_T$.

### 2. Discrete Case:

We define $X_n$ as follows:

$$X_n=X_0u^kd^{n-k}$$

Above, $u$ and $d$ are "up" and "down" multiplicative factors on a binomial tree, we therefore have $k\sim Bin(n,p)$.

Going with the Cox-Ross-Rubinstein parameters for "up" and "down", we set $u:=e^{\eta\frac{T}{n}+\sqrt{\frac{T}{n}}\sigma}$ and $d:=e^{\eta\frac{T}{n}-\sqrt{\frac{T}{n}}\sigma}$.

First of all, using CLT (which works well for Binomial if $p$ is close to 0.5), we have:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}k\xrightarrow{d}N(np,\sqrt{np(1-p)})$$

We can write:

$$ln \left( \frac{X_n}{X_0} \right) = k \left( 2 \sqrt{\frac{T}{n}} \sigma \right) + n\left(\eta \frac{T}{n}-\sqrt{\frac{T}{n}}\sigma\right) $$

Which gives:

$$\mathbb{E}\left[ln \left( \frac{X_n}{X_0} \right)\right]=\sqrt{Tn}\sigma(2p-1)+\eta T $$

$$Var\left(ln \left( \frac{X_n}{X_0} \right) \right)=4T\sigma^2p(1-p))$$

And again using CLT, we get:

\begin{equation}
\boxed{\lim_{n\to\infty}\left( \frac{X_n}{X_0} \right)\xrightarrow{d}N(\sqrt{Tn}\sigma(2p-1)+\eta T,2\sqrt{T}\sigma\sqrt{p(1-p))}} (2) 
\end{equation}
Specifically, if we take $p=0.5$, we get the beatiful result:

\begin{equation}
\boxed{\lim_{n\to\infty}ln\left(\frac{X_n}{X_0}\right)\xrightarrow{d} N\left(\eta T,\sigma \sqrt{T}\right)} (3)
\end{equation}

And trivially, setting $\eta:=\mu -0.5\sigma^2$ will mean that the discrete model converges to the continuous GBM.

Now I would like to show that applying Radon-Nikodym derivative to the discrete case will preserve the variance, **at least in the limit**.

We know that $k\sim Bin(n,p)$, therefore we can write $k:=\sum_{i=1}^{n}B_i$, with $B_i\sim Bernoulli(p)$. We could then define the Radon-Nikodym for the discrete case as follows: $\frac{\mathbb{dQ}}{\mathbb{dP}}=a$ when $B_i=1$ and $\frac{\mathbb{dQ}}{\mathbb{dP}}=b$ when $B_i=0$ for some constants $a$ and $b$. Then we have:

$$\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}[k]=\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}\left[\frac{\mathbb{dQ}}{\mathbb{dP}}k\right]=\sum_{i=0}^{i=n}p*a*1=npa=np^{\mathbb{Q}}$$

This brings us back to equation (2), where we can replace $p$ with $p^{\mathbb{Q}}$. Under the assumption that the original $p$ was set to 0.5, it is clear that $p^{Q}$ is no longer 0.5 (if for example $a:=\frac{2}{3}$ and $b:=\frac{4}{3}$, we have $p^{\mathbb{Q}}=\frac{1}{3}$).

It is now clear that after changing the measure, the variance is no longer preserved.

**QUESTION**: The fact that the discrete case converges to the GBM continuous case when we set $p=0.5$, but doesn't  seem  to converge perfectly onto the GBM when $p\neq0.5$ strikes me as odd. I would also like to get an intuition for why the variance is preserved under change of measure for the continuous case, but isn't for the discrete case.

I would appreciate any tips or hints, and specifically, references to any papers that might deal with this specific problem. Thank you so much,

Comment: I am following this with interest from the other site. One thought I had:  in a binomial tree, you cannot change the drift by more than a certain amount (because the expected value of the drift adjusted process cannot be higher than the maximum possible value or lower than the minimum).  But, if indeed you choose a drift adjustment like that, which attains the maximum or minimum value, then the variance must vanish.  So basically you can’t always preserve variance if the range of outcomes is finite.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79875/laws-of-b-t-t-in-0-t-and-2b-t-t-in-0-t-singular

This seems to be the answer.  Need to preserve quadratic variation otherwise you have null sets not the same in the two measures

Comment: You wrote $\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}[k] = \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[\frac{d\mathbb{P}}{d\mathbb{Q}} k]$. It should be the other way around.

Comment: Also, just because the variance changes, that could be convergence to a time-change of Geometric Brownian motion. But [dm63](https://mathoverflow.net/users/476107/dm63) is absolutely right about the relevance of the other post on Math Stack Exchange. (I vote for that answer.) The two limits are mutually singular because of the different variance/quadratic-variation process. You should look at MSE. I think this also should have been posted at Math Stack Exchange instead of Math Overflow.

Comment: Sorry I only had time to look at this now. If I find the time I'll try to contribute in the next week, but no guarantees .

Comment: @ShannonStarr: thank you for the feedback, I corrected the typo with the Radon-Nikodym derivative. I had originally posted a related question on MathSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4365831/does-radon-nikodym-derivative-affect-the-variance-of-a-random-variable), but it received no satisfactory answer, whilst a number of contributors reached out to me to say the problem was of interest. I then spent a couple of days on the problem to try to solve it: the post here on MathOverflow shows where I am currently stuck. I think the questions is borderline professional mathematics.